# Perturbing PDF with spatial dependent perturbation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, perturbation-theory, complex-systems

Let's consider a PDF $\rho(x)$, with normalization 1. Let's perturb it in the following way:
$$
\rho(x+\varepsilon F(x) ),
$$
with $\varepsilon$ small. I impose that the perturbed PDF is again a PDF with normalization one. 
I think that the following formula, which describes the linear variation of the PDF, holds:
$$
\rho(x+\varepsilon F(x) ) - \rho(x)= \varepsilon \partial_{x}[F(x)\rho(x)],
$$ 
since it preserves normalization, but I do not know how I can prove it.

N.B. If the initial $\rho(x)$ satisfies a Fokker-Planck equation, I found it to be true.

Comment: Expanding for small $\epsilon$ yields to linear order  $\rho(x + \epsilon F(x)) = \rho(x) + \epsilon F(x) \partial_x [\rho(x)] + O(\epsilon^2)$. So if your conjectured relation is true, then $F(x)$ must be a constant (at least if $\rho$ is differentiable). So equivalently you can ask whether or not it is possible to find a non-constant function $F$ for which the perturbed density would remain normalized for any value of $\epsilon$. I was not able to find such an $F$, but was not yet able to prove that non exists.

Answer (score 0):

Define $y = x + \epsilon F(x)$ and denote (conforming to the common physicist's abuse of notation) $\rho(y)$ to be the PDF of $y$. According to the change of variables formula for PDFs, $$\rho(x) = \rho(y) \frac{dy}{dx} = \rho(x+\epsilon F(x))[1+\epsilon F'(x)].$$ Expanding to first order in $\epsilon$ yields the required relation: $$0 = \rho'(x)F(x) + \rho(x) F'(x) = \partial_x [\rho(x)F(x)].$$

I believe that this result, together with my comment above, imply that the only choice of $F(x)$ that yields a legitimate (normalized) PDF for all $\epsilon$ is a global translation, $y = x + \epsilon c$, i.e., it is not space dependent (unless $F$ or $\rho$ are not smooth enough, in which case this perturbative argument might fail).